# Selenium Webdriver - XPath: How to use 'and' 'Or' in xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to create XPath as `//a[class='btn btn-invisible btn-link routeLink'] and //a[data-route='#Leads']`.

Other example: `//div[@class='btn-group'] and //a[@text()='Leads']`

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" style="display: none;">
<a class="btn btn-invisible btn-link routeLink" data-route="#Leads" href="#Leads">Leads</a>
```

Comment: Please watch your formatting and check the preview before posting a question. Your HTML disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below is what you need:

```
1) //a[@class='btn btn-invisible btn-link routeLink'][@data-route='#Leads']


2) //div[@class='btn-group'][text()='Leads']
```

and if you really need to use 'and' then niharika_neo's suggestion should work too.

Answer (score 2):

```
//a[@class='btn btn-invisble' and data-route='#Leads']
```

In the second example: Do you want a div or do you want an anchor?  Shouldn't those be different locators?

You can or them as such using a pipe: `//div[@class='x']|//a[@text='aa']`.